# Svelte (routify) + rollup: not watching for css changes in /static

Tags: svelte, rollup

I want to be able to watch for changes in /static (for example, on global.css)

I am using the following code to watch for changes on my static directory:

```
        watch: {
            clearScreen: false,
            include: ["static/**", "src/**"]
        },
```

I also tried calling add "css" to the --extensions option in routify cli:
`routify -D --extensions svelte,html,md,css`

However nothing works, and I can't seem to trigger a rebuild on changes to css files... Any advice?

Thanks!

Comment: Changes to assets located in `static/` shouldn't require a full rebuild anyway, so there's really no need to watch these files. You don't see the changes after doing a browser clear cache + reload?

Comment: Routify copies the contents of /static/ to /build/static, so any changed files must be copied. I am aware that rollup-plugin-copy is performing that operation at the beginning of each build, but then it stops watching and updating files from /static.
I tried setting copyOnce: false in the options for rollup-plugin-copy, but that didn't help, and furthermore it made the ordinary svelte files not being updated properly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Rollup watches only the files that are included in your bundle (i.e. that have been `import`ed in a file directly or indirectly imported from your entry point -- `input` in your Rollup config). Said otherwise, files that are not imported but merely referenced in `index.html` can't rely on Rollup watcher. We would need a copy plugin with its own file watcher, but currently there are none.

If it's just for CSS assets, you can use `rollup-plugin-postcss` and `import './global.css'` from your `main.js` instead of having it directly in the `static` directory. Here's an [article](https://johanronsse.be/2020/05/01/how-to-add-postcss-to-routify/) with detailed explanations on how to do just that.

...

Well, since I started writing this answer, there is now a copy plugin with watch capability: [rollup-plugin-copy-watch](https://www.npmjs.com/package/rollup-plugin-copy-watch).

So if you need more than just CSS, or if you don't want to include your `global.css` into your build process, you can use that instead.

Install in your project:

```sh
yarn add -D rollup-plugin-copy-watch
```

In your `rollup.config.js`, change the import:

```js
// import copy from 'rollup-plugin-copy'
import copy from 'rollup-plugin-copy-watch'
```

And add a `watch` option to the `copy` plugin (also added `verbose` in the example, to ensure it works):

```js
      copy({
        targets: [
          { src: staticDir + '/**/!(__index.html)', dest: distDir },
          { src: `${staticDir}/__index.html`, dest: distDir, rename: '__app.html', transform },
        ],
        copyOnce: true,
        flatten: false,

        watch: staticDir,
        verbose: true,
      }),
```

Comment: That's excellent, thank you so much!! This is exactly what I was looking for. Both options seem reasonable, I'll try and see which one adjusts better to my setup.
I assume that copy-watch is more useful when I have many assets in static that I want to watch for, while importing the .css in my main.js seems a fair solution for simply one file... am I correct?

Comment: The copy watch option is easier to setup and will handle more cases, if you have images, fonts, etc. in your static folder. The postcss option will actually slow your (re)build a little (since now css is part of the bundle), BUT it can support advanced usage, like SASS, autoprefixing, etc. I think this is on this last point that I would base my decision. FWIW both solutions are not incompatible or exclusive of each other.